# Accessing a website's directory in IIS from File Zilla

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net, ftp, settings

I have my Asp.net website deployed in my IIS's Virtual directory. Usually a FTP software like File Zilla is used to upload files to a website's directory from a remote system. File Zilla asks for a **Host** name, **Username**, **password** to connect to the remote server.

Now all I want is my users in LAN should be able to access this directory from their system using FTP software like FileZilla. So how can I provide the Host name, username and password to my website's directory.

I tried to find it on google but no help. Detailed steps please. Its IIS 5.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

You would enter the local IP address as the hostname and then enter a username and password for an account on the server.

Comment: Where can I create the username and password. I dont find any option to create in my IIS